# connection to dbase from jdbc on linux

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion, foxpro, dbase

Can we connect to a dBAse/FoxPro `.dbf` file on Linux using JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be vendors for cross-platform JDBC drivers such as [these folks](http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_dbf_jdbc.htm). It is also possible to use a proxy, with a server running on Windows and JDBC driver on Linux.

Comment: @Juan sounds like you have an issue using J-Stels in a particular scenario. That does not make this answer invalid. Why not start a new question to see whether there is a solution to your problem.

Comment: Done. I have a related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326959/stelsdbf-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space