# StelsDBF java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: jdbc, foxpro, dbase

I am using a evaluation version of [StelsDBF JDBC Driver 5.2](http://www.csv-jdbc.com/download.htm#StelsDBF) 
I have a dbf file with 8302 rows and 43 cols 5mb and StelsDBF seems not working.
StelsDBF works fine with other smaller files.

My query

```
select codi,descrip from \"DATA.DBF\" limit 10
```

When I try to get the results I get the following

```
Exception in thread "'DATA.DBF' producer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at jstels.database.b.d.if(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.database.b.e.do(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.dbf.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.common.h2.OperationTable$a.do(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.common.h2.OperationTable$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.utils.b.b$a.run(Unknown Source)
```

I added the parameter **&dbPath=D:/juan/sync/syncro_db&tempPath=C:/Temp** and get the next

```
Exception in thread "'DATA.DBF' producer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at jstels.database.b.d.if(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.database.b.e.do(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.dbf.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.common.h2.OperationTable$a.do(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.common.h2.OperationTable$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.utils.b.b$a.run(Unknown Source)
java.sql.SQLException: [StelsDBF JDBC driver] Can't load the file 'DATA.DBF' to H2 database. Error was: Time is out in 'consumer' thread
    at jstels.jdbc.common.h2.OperationTables.loadTable(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.common.h2.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at jstels.jdbc.common.h2.g.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.rhemsolutions.customer.TestStelsDbf.main(TestStelsDbf.java:27)
```

I added VM arguments to my IDE too **-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx2048m** but get the same exceptions.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestStelsDbf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String drive = "D:/juan/dbf";

        try {
            Class.forName("jstels.jdbc.dbf.DBFDriver2");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          try {
//          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jstels:dbf:"+drive+"?extension=.DBF");
//            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jstels:dbf:"+drive+"?extension=.DBF&dbPath=D:/juan/sync/syncro_db&tempPath=C:/Temp");
              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jstels:dbf:"+drive+"?extension=.DBF&dbInMemory=false&tempPath=C:/Temp");

            String cli = "select codi,descrip from \"DATA.DBF\" limit 10";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(cli);
            for (int j = 1; j <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
                System.out.print(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(j) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
                  System.out.print(rs.getObject(j) + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
              }
             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for too many exceptions. Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a 32bit or 64 bit Java? If you're out of heap then you need more heap, maybe a 32bit Java can't have the heap expanded to the size you need.

Comment: I am using 64bit java and have 6g of RAM

Comment: so have you tried increasing the heap still further? Instead of -Xmx2048m try a bigger number. Do a few experiments. Set heap to a value, 8000 rows doesn't work, what's the biggest number of rows that does? Increase the heap by some amount. Now how many rows works. Pretty soon you have a model for how memory is being consumed and hence can see what's feasible

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you need to move the synchrobase out of the Java heap.

I notice you already tried with a persistent synchrobase.  Two suggestions:

1)  Do not use the root of a drive, but a directory.  Move your .DBF files there.

```
String drive = "D:/myDB";
```

2)  Try with a temporary synchrobase.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jstels:dbf:"+drive+"?extension=.DBF&dbInMemory=false&tempPath=C:/Temp");
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the vendor what JVM versions the product has been tested with?  If not possible, can you try an older JVM version, 32 bit.  One more research alternatives:  try not only with less rows, but also suppressing  columns, especially with unusual datatypes (did that exist in dBASE?  I don't remember).